# Combine two grouped query into one select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

How can I connect two grouped below query?

```
select [Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Quater],sum([colX])as X
from table1
group by [Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Quater];

select [Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Quater],sum([colY]) as Y
from table2
group by [Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Quater];
```

result should return column:
[Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Quater], X, Y

Comment: Connect how? Show us samples of separate results, and the combined result.

Comment: just updated question: FY, FQ, X, Y

Comment: [This](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/47861/22006) might help, they tried something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
select coalesce(t1.[Fiscal Year], t2.[Fiscal Year]) as [Fiscal Year], 
       coalesce(t1.[Fiscal Quater], t2.[Fiscal Quater]) as [Fiscal Quater],
       coalesce(t1.X, 0) as X, 
       coalesce(t2.Y, 0) as Y
from (
  select [Fiscal Year], [Fiscal Quater], sum([colX]) as X
  from table1
  group by [Fiscal Year], [Fiscal Quater]) as t1
full join (
  select [Fiscal Year], [Fiscal Quater], sum([colY]) as Y
  from table2
  group by [Fiscal Year], [Fiscal Quater]
) as t2 on t1.[Fiscal Year] = t2.[Fiscal Year] and 
           t1.[Fiscal Quater] = t2.[Fiscal Quater]
```

Comment: it;s possible to add one more column, that will show X value from previous year?

Comment: column Fiscal Year is Varchar type

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` the two tables together in a derived table, do `GROUP BY` at main level:

```
select [Fiscal Year], [Fiscal Quater], sum([colX])as X, sum([colY]) as Y
from
(
select [Fiscal Year], [Fiscal Quater], colX, NULL as colY from table1
UNION ALL
select [Fiscal Year], [Fiscal Quater], NULL as colX, colY from table2
)
group by [Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Quater]
```

Alternatively, do double `GROUP BY`:

```
select [Fiscal Year], [Fiscal Quater], sum(X), sum(Y) 
from
(
    select [Fiscal Year], [Fiscal Quater], sum([colX]) as X, NULL as Y
    from table1
    group by [Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Quater];
    UNION ALL
    select [Fiscal Year], [Fiscal Quater], NULL as X, sum([colY]) as Y
    from table2
    group by [Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Quater]
)
group by [Fiscal Year],[Fiscal Quater]
```

Perhaps optimized differently?

Answer (score 0):

You could use following CTE's:

```
WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT [Fiscal year], [Fiscal  quater], Value = colX FROM   table1 
),
T2 AS
(
    SELECT [Fiscal year], [Fiscal quater], Value = colY FROM   table2
)
SELECT [T1.Fiscal Year],[T1.Fiscal Quater],
       X = SUM(T1.Value),
       Y = SUM(T2.Value)
FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN T2
    ON T1.[Fiscal year]   = T2.[Fiscal year] 
   AND T1.[Fiscal quater] = T2.[Fiscal quater] 
GROUP  BY [T1.Fiscal Year], T1.[Fiscal quater]
```